# A four-letter word in two ways

Tags: riddle, word

Containing four letters,
Making two sounds.

One of the options,
Feminine and plural.

The other one is
Third-person singular.

What's this word
That baffles me?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is

> does

Feminine and plural

> Does are several female deer, so it qualifies.

Third-person singular

> The verb "does" is pronounced differently and is the third person singular form of do.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I was going for. Well done.

Answer (score 10):

Alternative answer (in a similar vein to that given by SteveV)

> Sows

One of the options,
Feminine and plural.

> A sow is a female pig

The other one is
Third-person singular.

> To sow means to plant a seed by scattering it on or in the earth

Making two sounds.

> The first way rhymes with "cows", the second rhymes with "goes".

Comment: Another good option! I didn't realise there was more than one possibility matching these clues ... although SteveV's answer is a more common word.

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> ELSE

Containing four letters,
Making two sounds.

> It contains four letters and makes the sounds El and S.

One of the options,
Feminine and plural.

> ELLES in french which is feminine and plural sounds like EL.

The other one is
Third-person singular.

> SE in french meaning itself and so third-person singular sounds like S.

Comment: No, but good try. The "two sounds" part is a bit of a stretch, I think. No knowledge of non-English languages is needed here.